# Logic for SETTING/PASSING data from online XML to Image buttons in Table layout

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, android-tablelayout, saxparser

I made the seating arrangements layouts in XML Table Layout format and I **want to set the XML data from URL to set in the layours below.**

---

**I made the layout like below**

---

[image: image1]

---

**Now need the logic and hint as to how to populate the data into each sets like below**

---

```
    SAXParserFactory saxPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxP = saxPF.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xmlR = saxP.getXMLReader();
URL url = new URL("http://www.xxxxx.com"); // URL of the XML
/**
* Create the Handler to handle each of the XML tags.
**/
XMLHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
xmlR.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
xmlR.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
data = XMLHandler.data;
/**
* Makes the TextView length the size of the TextView arrays by getting the size of the
**/
title = new TextView[data.getTitle().size()];
artist = new TextView[data.getArtist().size()];
country = new TextView[data.getCountry().size()];
company = new TextView[data.getCompany().size()];
price = new TextView[data.getPrice().size()];
year = new TextView[data.getYear().size()];
/**
* Run a for loop to set All the TextViews with text until
* the size of the array is reached.
*
**/
for (int i = 0; i < data.getTitle().size(); i++) {
title[i] = new TextView(this);
title[i].setText("xxxx = "+data.getTitle().get(i));
artist[i] = new TextView(this);
artist[i].setText("xxxx = "+data.getArtist().get(i));
country[i] = new TextView(this);
country[i].setText("Country = "+data.getCountry().get(i));
company[i] = new TextView(this);
company[i].setText("xxxx = "+data.getCompany().get(i));
price[i] = new TextView(this);
price[i].setText("Price = "+data.getPrice().get(i));
year[i] = new TextView(this);
year[i].setText("xxxx = "+data.getYear().get(i));
((ViewGroup) layout).addView(title[i]);
((ViewGroup) layout).addView(artist[i]);
((ViewGroup) layout).addView(country[i]);
((ViewGroup) layout).addView(company[i]);
((ViewGroup) layout).addView(price[i]);
((ViewGroup) layout).addView(year[i]);
}
setContentView(layout);
}
}
```

**I am using this link** [click here](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-xml-parsing)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a matrix[ROWS][COLS] of type Seat object if you know the rows and cols of seats that you have.
Seat object will contain the following data deck(int), height,width
when you are creating all the ui you will need to populate the data depending the indexes you are getting from columnNo and rowNo

Comment: UI is done but the logic to populate the seats from xml is i am not getting